# Cannot write file in a folder

Tags: visual-web-part, file, solution

I cannot write a file into a folder through some  code in a VisualWebPart in a Sharepoint 2013 solution.
I've given write permission to c:\myfolder to Everyone.
The code I use to write  is the following:

```
String timestamp = Utility.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
            String folderpath = "" + @"c:\myfolder";
            String spyfile = ddlquery.SelectedValue + "_" + timestamp + ".txt";
            string spypath = folderpath + "\\" + spyfile;

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(spypath, "Test test test...");
```

I've even tried wrapping the code with

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
     ....
   });
```

but no luck.

The ULS log I get is this:

```
Application error when access /SitePages/mypage.aspx, Error=Could not find a part of the path 'c:\myfolder\myfile_20151030095052084.txt'.  
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)    
 at  


System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\myfolder\myfile_20151030095052084.txt'.   
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)    
 at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)    
 at
```

My code works on a development machine.
Any ideas, about what could be wrong?

**EDIT**:

solved with the code below following Atish Dipongkor hint.
Anyway, as strange as it may seems now I have two folders with the same name as the folder already existed.

```
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath))
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);

            }
```

Comment: check the folder if it exits before writing file

Comment: Your piece of advice has really helped me (see edit). If you want to put it as an answer, I'll flag it

Comment: Added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment, Exception arises when folder does not exit. So solution is following

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath))
            {
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);

            }
```

Needs to check the folder if it exists before writing file.

Answer (score 1):

In case this works on your DEV machine, but not in other environments, ensure the folder exists on all WFE servers of the farm (if there are many), as the code may be executed on any of them.