# Do File System Operation via app pool account

Tags: permissions, web-services, file

I have a service that is hosted in SharePoint. What I want to do is to access file system in the service, say create directories and files on the server (Web front end server). The current logged in user does not have permission on the file system and I don't want to give them permission.

What I am looking for is to do `System.IO` operations under application pool account. something like SharePoint's `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` but for IO operations. More specifically it is `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(string)` and also `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string,byte[])`

Is there a way to elevate privileges for these sorts of operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to perform System.IO operations.

Try below code:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    String folderpath = "" + @"c:\myfolder";
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderpath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderpath);
    }

    String timestamp = Utility.GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);

    String fileName = "test"+ "_" + timestamp + ".txt";
    string filePath = folderpath + "\\" + fileName;

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, "Test");
});
```

Reference - [Cannot write file in a folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/161056/cannot-write-file-in-a-folder)

Comment: I just tried it and yes right, I thought RunWithElevatedPrivileges only works in SharePoint Context. Thanks!